# ¿Por qué no cambia valor de TextView?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

Estoy creando una app para practicar sumas y tal, el detalle es que tengo dos TextView para mostrar los dos valores a Sumar, Restar, Multiplicar y Dividir.

De primera mano ocupo en botón que requiere de un primer toque a un botón para iniciar el "juego"

```
val btnComprobar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnComprobar)
    btnComprobar.setText("Empezar!")
    btnComprobar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {})
```

Cambia el texto del botón , Si.
Pero a la hora de poner los operandos de cada operación en pantalla, es donde no cambia:

```
var operando:Char = 'a'
    var txtOperando: TextView? = null
    var txtNumUno: TextView? = null
    var txtNumDos: TextView? = null



txtOperando = findViewById(R.id.txtOp) //Esto ya en onCreate
        txtNumUno = findViewById(R.id.txtNumU)
        txtNumDos = findViewById(R.id.txtNumD)
```

Procedo a ponerlos en blanco para que no haya confusión, aquí si que pone el texto de los TextView en blanco:

```
txtNumUno?.setText("")
    txtNumDos?.setText("")
```

procedo a recibir que operacion quiere hacer por medio de intent, para cambiar el simbolo de que tipo de operacion es en el TextView correpsondiente (y si, cambia el texto de txtoperando):

```
 val operacion = intent.getStringExtra("operacion")
   



    if(operacion.equals("suma")){
        operando = '+'
        txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
    }else{
        if (operacion.equals("resta")){
            operando = '-'
            txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
        }else{
            if (operacion.equals("multiplicacion")){
                operando = '*'
                txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
            }else{
                if (operacion.equals("division")){
                    operando = '/'
                    txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

El detalle, al iniciar el "Juego", si cambia el texto del botón (por "Empezar!"), pero NUNCA Cambia al nuevo numero random que le asigno en cada operando de la operación (txtNumUno y txtNumDos):

```
val btnComprobar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnComprobar)
    btnComprobar.setText("Empezar!")
    btnComprobar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        var Primero:Boolean = true
        if(Primero){
            btnComprobar.setText("Comprobar...")
            Primero = false
        }else{
            var NumU:Int = 0
            NumU = (1..100).random()
            var NumD:Int = 0
            NumD = (1..100).random()
            txtNumUno?.setText(NumU.toString()) //Desde aqui no cambia nada, sigue en blanco
            txtNumDos?.setText(NumD.toString()) //Igual que el anterior

            var res:Int

            if(operando == '+'){
                 res = NumU + NumD
                if(res == edrespuesta?.text.toString().toInt()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto! +100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //no muestra ni este toast al tocar boton
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Estas Mal! -100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }else{
                if (operando == '-'){
                    res = NumU - NumD
                    if(res == edrespuesta?.text.toString().toInt()){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto! +100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Estas Mal! -100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }else{
                    if (operando == '*'){
                        res = NumU * NumD
                    }else{
                        if (operando == '/'){
                            res = NumU / NumD
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    })
```

Una disculpa si es una duda novata, desarrolle apps pero hace dos años y eso con java; no entiendo aun del todo Kotlin.
De antemano Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es un simple error de lógica. Estás declarando la variable `Primero` dentro del clickListener, entonces cada vez que presionas el botón se vuelve a crear esa variable con el valor `true` y por lo tanto jamás va a entrar al bloque `else`.

```
btnComprobar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    var Primero: Boolean = true
    if (Primero) {
        ...
    } else {
```

Todo lo necesitas hacer para solucionarlo es mover la declaración de la variable afuera del listener:

```
var Primero: Boolean = true
btnComprobar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {        
    if (Primero) {
        ...
    } else {
```

Comment: Gracias Men, me sirvio; una disculpa si fue algo precoz la duda

Comment: De nada, te recomiendo leer sobre la expresión [when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) de kotlin que sirve para evitar esos if anidados